# How to put current filename in vim commands in .vimrc

Tags: vim, neovim

i want to create a shortcut to run typescript in vim how can i access the filename in `.vimrc`
i want to run short scripts.

`nmap <leader>r :! ts-node current-file<return>`

Answer (score 3):

First try `%`, as this gets substituted by the file name (as explained in `:help :!`):

```
nmap <Leader>r :! ts-node %<CR>
```

But if the file name contains whitespaces or special characters, you might see some errors. In that case, you need to escape the file name as follows:

```
nmap <Leader>r :execute '!ts-node ' . shellescape(expand("%"))<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're strongly adviced to read `:h cmdline.txt`, section 6 `:h cmdline-special` from top down to bottom.

```
nnoremap <leader>r  :!ts-node %:S<CR>
```